# Display tag changing format of number

Tags: java, struts2, export, export-to-excel, displaytag

I am using display tag to export data to Excel its working fine but I have a column named as Account number where the values will be of 16 digits.

Example:

```
01152144XXXX9625 and 1157XXXXXXXXX526
```

For first number starting with 0 it displays as 1152144XXXX9625 without 0. For second number it displays in the format of 2.32006E+15 when we change the format from Excel to number corresponding number get rounded to 1157XXXXXXXXX530.

```
<display:column property="SB_ACC_NO" title="Saving Account Number" sortable="false" headerClass="td_bg_2" />
```

I tried to add property as format="{0,number,0}" but same result is obtained.

Comment: I am using like this <display:column property="SB_ACC_NO" title="Saving Account Number" sortable="false" headerClass="td_bg_2" />

Comment: What you really want is to use it like a string.

Comment: Kindly guide how to set it to string